# Can companies source paywalled scientific articles from authors?

Tags: industry, open-access, literature-search, paywall

I work for a company in the medical sector that, among other things, conducts literature searches and submits them to regulators for approval prior to product launch. The company currently pays for most articles and I was wondering:

1. If the authors are approached by employees and in turn send over free copies of their paper, can the company get in legal trouble if it uses the free copy for commercial purposes?
2. Does it make a difference if the author need not be directly approached but freely shares their paper on their own website or in sites like ResearchGate?

EDIT: I should point out that I will definitely not take advice here and apply it without legal consult - my objective with asking this question is merely to *rule in* the plausibility of such an approach to acquiring access to scientific literature based on other researchers' shared experiences.

Comment: If I worked for the company, I would make sure that all materials were sourced through the copyright portal we had a contract with. You say it is a medical regulatory field, so, really, the dollars/Euros/whatnot are peanuts. If you get a copy directly from the author and wish to use it for company purposes, get another copy through your standard process. As one further twist, where I work the articles we don't have direct access to come with a cover page that notes it is for 'Internal Business Use Only' - so, not for submission to another body.

Comment: @JonCuster So it's a non-starter - thank you for your input!

Comment: "The company currently pays for most articles"  I do not believe you have this right.  The company pays for a bundle of subscriptions, which is not quite the same as paying for individual articles.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Maybe some companies...but in my brief corporate life, yeah, the company bought individual articles. No one was selling bundled subscriptions in a sufficiently narrow/targeted way to make any sense to a corporate customer - those subscriptions are for academic customers whose readers have very broad interests as a collective. Let's say an article costs $50 to access, 2 employees cost $100k each; that's 4000 articles. No pharma company is going to blink at that.

Comment: @BryanKrause "sufficiently narrow/targeted way to make any sense to a corporate customer" Are any of these companies familiar? Their activities are certainly not narrow. https://companiesmarketcap.com/biotech/largest-companies-by-market-cap/

Comment: "an article costs $50 to access"  plus hours of lost employee time required to organize a purchase in a bureaucracy.

Comment: What exactly does the company submit to the regulators? Is it a literature review that simply overviews the field and cites articles, or are the actual cited articles included in a larger bundle?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes, they are very narrow compared to academic scholarship. Very very few papers are of interest even to a large pharmaceutical company.

Comment: @Anyon The company develops a product that needs to be supported by a scientific report that proves the concept behind its use is valid. This is where a literature review is needed - it provides evidence that similar implementations have been beneficial to patients in the past.

Comment: @AnastasiosTsarouchas Right, that much was clear to me from the question. I'm just saying that depending on what said reports include you might implicate copyright law as well as whatever terms and conditions the publisher applies to the accessing the material. E.g. attaching cited papers to the report (which I think some government agencies require) could make for a commercial use of a copyrighted work, whereas just citing ideas or results does not implicate copyright in jurisdictions I'm familiar with. But details matter and IANAL, so probably best to discuss that with your legal counsel.

Answer (score 11):

As a company, you may want to consult a lawyer rather than collect opinions of random people on the internet (and IANAL, btw). Also, I am not sure the language in your question is precise enough. The copies that authors have are not "free", they can be used free of charge for particular purpose(s). Similarly, the copies made available via websites such as RG or personal pages, can be "freely downloaded" (meaning that there is no paywall), but it does not imply they can be freely used for any purpose imaginable. Even if you got a pdf, someone still holds the copyright and other derivative rights, and you need to carefully assess how your purposes agree with these protected rights.

In general, saying that your purposes are "commercial" may not be sufficient to make a judgement --- this is why you may need to consult a lawyer.  Regulations differ from country to country and from one area to another. For example, the way how medical regulators work in the US may be completely different from how, say, Engineering patents work in India. You may want to protect yourself and your company against consequences of an ill-informed decision. If you want to save money on article fees, contact a lawyer first to make sure this is safe and won't cost your company a fortune in fines.

Comment: "it does not imply they can be freely used for any purpose imaginable."  The question is pretty clear that the use is a "fair use" which is permitted in the USA.

Comment: "cost your company a fortune in fines."  This is a bit misleading.  Copyright litigation is usually civil litigation.  Criminal prosecution does exist, but is quite obscure.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist If the use is definitely fair use, then there's no issue. You don't need anyone's permission so long as you can acquire a copy by any lawful method.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist OP never said that they are in the USA. It is not at all clear to me that their purpose falls under fair use policy in their jurisdiction.

Comment: The company is EU-based but seeks to apply for FDA approval for some of its products as well.

Answer (score -3):

> If the authors are approached by employees and in turn send over free copies of their paper, can the company get in legal trouble if it uses the free copy for commercial purposes?

For recent, main stream publications, the agreement between the author and the publisher allows the author to do that.  Nobody will get in trouble.

> Does it make a difference if the author need not be directly approached but freely shares their paper on their own website?

No.  For recent, main stream publications, the author is explicitly permitted to distribute works on their own website.  ResearchGate is a nuisance I won't address.

Even if the author has infringed on the publisher's copyright, [simply receiving that infringing material is not a breach of the publisher's copyright.](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#106)  Importing might be a breach.

Do not take legal advice from people on the internet.

Comment: This refers to US law.

Comment: IANAL but I don’t think you’re right, at least for paywalled papers.  IOP states explicitly here: https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/author-rights-policies/ that sharing is restricted (in particular but not exclusively to teaching purposes).  Likewise APS states here: https://journals.aps.org/copyrightFAQ.html#PDF that sharing pdf is also limited, this time for research purposes.  It’s a stretch to suggest either apply to the OP.  The copyright might not be practically enforceable, but my reading is that what the OP suggests is not in accordance with the copyright agreement.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Your own links show you are wrong. "may use all or part of the APS published article, including the APS-prepared version (e.g., the PDF from the online journal) without revision or modification, on the author's or employer's website" "authors can share a preprint of their article anywhere and at any time"  I strongly disagree that the author is not conducting research.  Obviously distributing a research article for people to read is distributing it for research purposes.  Reading research articles is an example of research.

Comment: again IANAL, and wording in this situation is essential but that company is not the one doing research inasmuch as none of the people at that company are part of a research lab; *presumably* none of their names appear or is likely to appear on a grant or grant proposal; rather, they are explicitly contracted out for regulatory help.  So it might be legal for an author to share the paper to an MD actually doing the research (or another person doing the research), but it's not so clear to me that this extends to a company doing literature search on behalf of the researcher.  (I could be wrong.)

Comment: (The distinction here is with the use of the paper: I can't see how, in the context of the OP, the paper is used for research purposes but lawyers read things in their own ways and I could very well be wrong.)

Comment: Your reasons why the activity is not research do not make sense.   What the organization is called or who is an author just doesn't matter.

Comment: exactly.  what matter is the *use* of the paper, and it is difficult to argue that the OP is using it for research, since this is clearly not.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero These agreements are between the author and the publisher though. In what jurisdictions would third parties such as OP's company be bound by them unless they agree to the terms when receiving the PDF from an author? (Which seems unlikely if it's just hosted on the author's website, but I digress.)

Comment: @Anyon yes it may not be enforceable because of this type of issue but one could imagine that a publisher could refuse to publish work by this author.  But then again, how would a publisher know that the OP obtained the paper from the author?